# Not able to Close blackberry 7 browser from my code

Tags: blackberry-webworks

Thanks! Hello everyone! I am making a BlackBerry 7 mobile native application. On click of button from my native application. It will be open a URL in a separate browser. So, I want to close the opened browser. The URL it is opening. This URL is separate domain, but this is my page, in this page i have tried following code. But, it is not working - 
    `blackberry.app.exit();`
    `window.close();`
    `System.exit();`

I have tried to open the URL in my native application using `iframe`. But, here always taking me splash screen instead of loading URL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WebWorks or Cordova (nee PhoneGap) ? One solution is to use Cordova 2.9 (the last version to support BBOS) and the InAppBrowser API.